# Problem with positive lookbehind and repeating pattern

Tags: .net, regex

Consider the following string:

```
ab(cd.xz) e(ab(fg).xz)) ab(hi.xz)
```

I want to match every substring that starts after ab( and ends with z. So I've written the following Regular Expression:

```
(?<=a.*?\().*?z
```

This should attempt to do the following according to RegexBuddy:

```
Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=a.*?\()»
   Match the character “a” literally «a»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character “(” literally «\(»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “z” literally «z»
```

The result I get in RegexBuddy are the following matches (notice the middle one is not working right, as it should match `fg).xz`). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex is working as designed :)

In the second example, the lookbehind expression matches `ab(cd.xz) e(`. The lookbehind match is always attempted from the start of the string onward (moving ahead if necessary), so the `.*?` matches more than you think. It is not (as one might expect) actually performed backwards from the current position.

So in the third example, the lookbehind even matches `ab(cd.xz) e(ab(fg).xz)) ab(`. It just happens to appear to work correctly because the actual match starts after another `ab(`...

Solution: Be more specific about what you allow to match. I suggest taking parentheses out of the allowed characters:

```
(?<=a[^()]*\().*?z
```

Comment: +1 not only does your example work, but you've explained what was wrong with mine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement is "starts after `ab(` and ends with `z`", then expression should be:

```
(?<=ab\().*?z
```

If you need to match to `a*(*z` and capture `*z` only, then this expression will work:

```
(?<=a[^(]*\().*?z
```